# Beginner- Second level looping through a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am currently trying my best to find the solution but my friends and I can't seem to find it !
The problem is the following, i have to compute the profit and loss for my investment portfolio that is the following function:
(market_price-spot_price)*volume

So i have a dictionary called portfolio of four apps with the spot price and the volume.
And an another dictionary called market with the market price for each app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4rLy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXtgT.png)

So i managed to compute the pnl (profit and loss) for the aapl stock but i cant manage a way to automatize it with a loop.
Could you help me with that please ?
I show you what i did with the aapl stock with the thrid image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2NPO.png)

Thanks for reading until here !

Comment: Instead of linked images. paste your code here using the code markup. (three `'s)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly here is a solution for your problem:

```py
pnl = {}

for name, value in portfolio.items():
    pnl[name] = (market[name] - portfolio[name]['strike']) * portfolio[name]['volume']
print(pnl)
```

With this piece of code `pnl` will be a dictionary with the name of the app as key and as value the calculated value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did work ! I didn't think about creating a dictionnary for the pnl !

Comment: If the solution answers your question you can "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

`pnl=0

#Compute the pnl with a dictionary

for name,value in portfolio.items():
pnl += (market[name]-(portfolio[name]['strike']))*(portfolio[name]['volume'])
print(pnl)   `

This work perfectly too !